# PHP soapClient __getLastRequest() returns only 21d650036748112168d66622aa01185e8c

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm trying to get my SOAP client working and do face a strange behavior for hours now:

```
$client = new SoapClient(".....", array('trace' => 1));
$result = $client->......();
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
```

this echoes: 21d650036748112168d66622aa01185e8c
but not the XML.

Comment: There is a  program available here: http://www.soapui.org/ . Download the program if you can & install it and then insert your WDSL URL and insert the function name to check that you are indeed calling the right function & passing it the correct params.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the source code, You will see the XML. Other possibility, use PHP htmlentities function to echo the request :
echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";

Answer (score 0):

I believe user2903575 is correct.  What you are most likely seeing is the browser's rendering of the XML envelope.  If you go to the usual page->view source, or use a tool like FireBug or Chrome's Inspect Element, you should be able to see the entire XML request in there.